# BindingSource.ListChanged Event won't fire when data is changed - isn't it supposed to?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

I am trying to get my grid to refresh automatically when the underlying data is updated in the database.  Isn't this supposed to work?  Or am I missing something?

I created a DataTable within my DataSet.  Then I created a new form and added a DataGridView (actually I'm using DevExpress' XtraGrid but am trying to get it to work with just the Microsoft controls).  I use the menu in the upper left of the grid to set the grid datasource to the datatable in the project data source.  This then automatically adds the dataset, BindingSource, and TableAdapter to the form.

Then when I add a BindingSource.ListChanged event it fires a few times when the form loads but not when any underlying data is changed.

Should the even fire when the data in the database changes?  Or is it only if the data is changed from somewhere else in the current VB.NET process?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listchanged event will only fire when the bound object changes, not when the data changes in the db.

If you are retrieving data from the db using sqlclient you can implement SQL dependency http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

Comment: Seems interesting but I saw that SQL Dependency is described as "fragile"....  Was hoping for an easy solution =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the behavior of the DevExpress XtraGrid, but for most databinding to lists, the `ListChanged` event only fires when the list is replaced with an entirely new different list.

If the list remains the same, but items are added to it, then it doesn't count as being a changed list. Generally you need to put some list in which implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface to handle items getting added on the fly

Answer (score 0):

this event Occurs when the underlying list changes or an item in the list changes. not when db change.

Here your Dataset or DataTable is loaded from data in the database but ones loaded there is no live connection between database and dataset data. If you need to save/update or refresh dataset then you have to call relevant method to do the task.

If you changing data from the Same UI where you show the data, call grid refresh method to reflect changes to gridview.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't fully understand...  What is the difference between the underlying list and the underlying data?  Is there no way to have the grid refresh automatically other than using a timer or something else like that?